# NullReferenceException at GetCompletionsAsync on Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-completion, roslyn-code-analysis

I try to get code completion, but when I try to get completions async by `CompletionService` I get `NullReferenceException`.

Here is a piece of code:

```
public async Task<IList<ICompletionData>> GetCompletionData(String code, int offset)
    {
        IList<ICompletionData> completionData = null;

        if (_workspace != null)
        {
            _workspace.Dispose();
        }
        _workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
        _project = _workspace.AddProject("Test", LanguageNames.CSharp);



        var sourceText = SourceText.From(code);
        var document = _workspace.AddDocument(_project.Id, "Compilation0", sourceText); 
        var completionService = CompletionService.GetService(document);
        var charCompletion = GetCompletionTrigger('.');
        var data = await completionService.GetCompletionsAsync(_document, offset,charCompletion,).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (data == null || data.Items.Any() == false)
            return new List<ICompletionData>();

        completionData = data.Items.Select(item => new RoslynCodeCompletion(_document, item)).ToList<ICompletionData>();

        return completionData;
    }
```

Error at line:

```
var data = await completionService.GetCompletionsAsync(_document, offset,charCompletion,).ConfigureAwait(false);//NullReferenseException.
```

Script code codepletion triggers by '.' (dot) symbol:

```
var str="";
str. // here calls `GetCompletionData`
```

Full code snippet is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zSURfPeH)

Comment: Are you sure `CompletionService.GetService(document);` returns non-null? The AdHoc workspace doesn't setup that by default, and looking at your code, it looks like you're not setting it up yourself, as well.

Comment: @Ties,hm..yes it is null!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This became a lot easier after [Roslyn PR #14921](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/14921) was merged. Before you had to a lot of [manual MEF configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12218), but now it should be enough to have the following nuget packages installed:

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features

And Roslyn will do the required configuration.